# Parsing json from a class attribute value string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a select dropdown that populates json data for years. the json data is stored in a div class and i have the variable `var url = JSON.parse(document.getElementById("fitmentData").getAttribute("class"));` to get the json from the div class. in the console, url actually does grab the json data, but the info is not populating in select dropdown.

html

```
<div id="fitmentData" class='[
    { "brand" : "Honda" , "model" : "SL350" , "year" : "1969" }, 
    { "brand" : "Honda" , "model" : "SL175" , "year" : "1970" }, 
    { "brand" : "Honda" , "model" : "SL350" , "year" : "1970" }, 
    { "brand" : "Honda" , "model" : "SL175" , "year" : "1971" }, 
    { "brand" : "Honda" , "model" : "SL350" , "year" : "1971" }, 
    { "brand" : "Honda" , "model" : "SL175" , "year" : "1972" }, 
    { "brand" : "Honda" , "model" : "SL350" , "year" : "1972" }, 
    { "brand" : "Honda" , "model" : "XL250" , "year" : "1972" }, 
    { "brand" : "Honda" , "model" : "XL175" , "year" : "1973" }, 
    { "brand" : "Honda" , "model" : "SL350" , "year" : "1973" }]'

    <select name="year" id="year"></select>
    <select id="make" name="make"></select>
    <select id="model" name="model"></select>

    // my js functions
</div>
```

js

```
<script>
    window.onload = function () {
        //year
        let yearDropdown = $('#year');
        yearDropdown.append('<option selected="true" disabled>Choose Year</option>')
                    .on('change', function () { })
    }

    var url = JSON.parse(document.getElementById("fitmentData").getAttribute("class"));

    //append json years in dropdown
    $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (key, entry) {
            yearDropdown.append($('<option>. </option>')
                        .attr('value', entry.year).text(entry.year));
        })
        //remove year duplicates
        var map = {}
        $('select option').each(function () {
            if (map[this.value]) {
                $(this).remove()
            }
            map[this.value] = true;
        })
    }
</script>
```

The Select Dropdown name populates and says Select Year, but no data is being populated in the dropdown.

Comment: you should be using data elements to store the JSON .. Not a class --  IE `data_json="(your json here)"`

Comment: Then you can retreive it like `$('#fitmentData').data("json")`

Comment: ok but url says it is grabbing the data from json in my console. Is there a way I can keep the json in the div class and still populate my select list? I was thinking there might be something wrong with this portion of the code  $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
           $.each(data, function (key, entry) {
            yearDropdown.append($('<option>.       
</option>').attr('value', entry.year).text(entry.year));
           })

Comment: @Zak is right that you should be using [custom data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes). Just make sure to use a hyphen instead of an underscore: `data-years=""`

Comment: @sean -- Good catch!

Comment: @DylanT What exception/error do you see in the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following changes are required:

1. The div tag was not closing - missing `>`
2. Kept the whole year population code inside window.onload otherwise,
   you have to declare yearDropdown outside window.onload function
3. When you do JSON.parse() you already have parsed data and you need
   not call API using this to fetch data again.
4. Modified the code that is appending the year options.

   var data = JSON.parse(document.getElementById("fitmentData").getAttribute("class"));

   $.each(data, function (key, entry) {
           yearDropdown.append($('<option>', {
               value: entry.year,
               text:  entry.year
           }));
       });

Please refer to the full running code [from github](https://github.com/fiveobjects/reference/blob/master/web/stack/57153380-PopulateDropdown.html)

And yes please do not use the class attribute to store data, instead, use data-* (e.g. data-year) attributes or fetch it from backend API.